# How to concatenate char*'s in C++?

Tags: c++, c++17

```
char *userstring;
std::cin >> userstring;
sql = "SELECT  datetime(last_visit_time/1000000-11644473600, 'unixepoch') as last_visited,    url,    title,    visit_count  FROM urls WHERE url LIKE '%%s"userstring"%';";'''
```

`userstring` is a `char*` defined by the user, and `sql` is also a `char*`.

`LIKE '%",userstring,"%';"; and LIKE '%"+userstring+"%';"; and LIKE '%%s"+userstring+"%';";`

but none of these work.

Comment: You should be using `std::string` instead as that supports concatenation with `+`.

Comment: NEVER concatenate user input into an SQL statement, that's how SQL injection happens.  https://xkcd.com/327/

Comment: @MarkRansom This is a completely hypothetical case. It's in a completely sealed off environment. No actual data will be lost. I'm not running microsoft. I just wanted to know how to do this. The only end user will be ME.

Comment: I don't care about your personal situation, any answer here might be seen by thousands.  If I could emphasize my warning, I would.

Comment: @MarkRansom Can I DM you for a real answer?

Comment: No, I think the advice you've already gotten to use `std::string` is sufficient.

Comment: I love Stack Overflow sometimes, lol.

Comment: @SubashChandra Microsoft is not a software, and injection is a thing that happens to any databases and any types of other software if not taken care

Comment: Probably still open. `strcat()` ?

Answer (score 2):

Take advantage of `std::string` which comes with **C++ STL** . `char *` is a C thing which requires very careful handling.